# Within rows of data frame, find first occurrence and longest sequence of value

Tags: r, tidyverse

Consider this data frame, which provides the scored responses on a 15-item test for 10 individuals:

```
library(tidyverse)
input <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~i1, ~i2, ~i3, ~i4, ~i5, ~i6, ~i7, ~i8, ~i9, ~i10, ~i11, ~i12, ~i13, ~i14, ~i15,
  "A", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  "B", 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  "C", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  "D", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
  "E", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  "F", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  "G", 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  "H", 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
  "I", 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  "J", 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1
)
```

I want R to go row-by-row, and scan the cells in each row from left to right, in order to create these new columns:

`first_0_name`: returns the column *name* of the cell containing the first occurrence of the value `0`

`first_0_loc`: returns the column *location* of the cell containing the first occurrence of the value `0`

`streak_1`: starting from the first occurrence of `0`, find the next occurrence of `1`, and then count how many consecutive `1` before the next occurrence of `0`.

The new columns should appear as below

```
new_cols <- tribble(
  ~first_0_name, ~first_0_loc, ~streak_1,
  "i9", 10, 5,
  "i4", 5, 4,
  "i6", 7, 8,
  "i8", 9, 4,
  "i9", 10, 5,
  NA, NA, NA,
  "i1", 2, 5,
  "i3", 4, 8,
  "i2", 3, NA,
  "i1", 2, 1
)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I see there is a typo on that row - my apologies.  Last row should be: `"i2", 3, 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit #2: Rewrote as combination of two summarizations.

```
input_tidy <- input %>%
  gather(col, val, -ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  mutate(col_num = row_number() + 1) 

input[,1] %>% 
  # Combine with summary of each ID's first zero
  left_join(input_tidy %>% filter(val == 0) %>%
              summarize(first_0_name = first(col),
                        first_0_loc = first(col_num))) %>%
  # Combine with length of each ID's first post-0 streak of 1's
  left_join(input_tidy %>%
              filter(val == 1 & cumsum(val == 1 & lag(val, default = 1) == 0) == 1) %>% 
              summarize(streak_1 = n()))


# A tibble: 10 x 4
   ID    first_0_name first_0_loc streak_1
   <chr> <chr>              <dbl>    <int>
 1 A     i9                    10        5
 2 B     i4                     5        4
 3 C     i6                     7        8
 4 D     i8                     9        4
 5 E     i9                    10        5
 6 F     NA                    NA       NA
 7 G     i1                     2        5
 8 H     i3                     4        8
 9 I     i2                     3       NA
10 J     i3                     4        2
```

Comment: This solution drops the first 6th row of the input data from the output, since it contains no zeros. OP's desired output seems to want to keep that row.

Comment: Edited to add right_join so all rows are included, even if NA.

Comment: I like the tidyverse solution, but there's still one cell that's not correct. In row 9 of your output, the value of `streak_1` should be `NA` because in that row there are no `1` values to the right of the first `0`.

Comment: I'll give it another look. Hack solution would be to use `replace_na(list(streak_1=0))` to replace streak of zero with NA.

Comment: Thank you! Your new code handles every case correctly, including some new variations I threw at it.

Comment: if you have a moment, I would like to understand better how this line works: `filter(val == 1 & cumsum(val == 1 & lag(val, default = 1) == 0) == 1) `. I understand that what it does is pare rows from the piped object such that the remaining rows, within each ID, begin with the first item scored `1` above the first `0`, and end with the last item scored `1` in the streak of consecutive `1`s. What I don't understand his how the logic and functions wrapped within `filter()` accomplish this outcome.

Comment: For that section, I want to keep just the rows where a) val == 1 and b) they're part of the first streak of 1's after a zero.   The `cumsum` part accomplishes the (b) part by keeping a running count of how many times we've had a `val == 1` which was preceded by a zero. We care about the first such streak, so we filter to just the ones where that cumulative count is 1.

Comment: So `(val == 1 & lag(val, default = 1) == 0)` identifies rows where val = 1, and which are preceded by a row where val = 0. Wrapping this in `cumsum()` then gives each of these rows a further identifier that says this row is part of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc, streak of 1s following a 0. And then finally we end up with the target set of rows by limiting the output to only rows where this `cumsum()` expression is equal to 1. The one part I'm still not clear about is the argument `default = 1`. What role does this argument play in grabbing the right set of rows?

Comment: Without `default = 1`, we'd get NA for the initial row, which has no lag, which would break the `cumsum`. `Default = 1` says "Treat the first row as if it were preceded by a 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199864/discussion-between-dsh-and-jon-spring).

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use base R a little more directly and avoid the cost of transforming the whole data frame. This solution also retains the order of rows without having to create extra ordering columns (unlike the tidyverse solution).

```
results <- apply(input, 1, function(x) {

  # get indices of all zeros
  zeros <- which(x == 0)

  # exit early if no zeros are found
  if (length(zeros) == 0) {
    return(data.frame(first_0_name = NA, first_0_loc = NA, streak_1 = NA))
  }

  first.name <- names(zeros[1])         # name of first 0 column
  first.idx <- zeros[1]                 # location of first zero
  longest.streak <- diff(zeros)[1] - 1  # length of first 0-0 streak

  return(data.frame(first_0_name = first.name, 
                    first_0_loc = first.idx, 
                    streak_1 = ifelse(longest.streak == 0, NA, longest.streak))
         )

})

output <- do.call(rbind, results)

    first_0_name first_0_loc streak_1
i9            i9          10        5
i4            i4           5        4
i6            i6           7        8
i8            i8           9       NA
i91           i9          10        5
1           <NA>          NA       NA
i1            i1           2        5
i3            i3           4        8
i2            i2           3       NA
i31           i3           4        2
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, in row 4 of your output, `streak_1` should be `4`, not `NA`. The code is not handling the consecutive `0` values in this row correctly.

Answer (score 0):

An option using `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(input), id.var = 'ID')[, .(first_o_name = first(variable[value == 0]), 
    first_o_loc = which(value == 0)[1] +1,
    streak_1 = sum(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(value == 0) < 0)) == 2) - 1 ),  ID
     ][streak_1 < 0, streak_1 := NA_real_][]
```

---

A `base R` option can also be with `apply` and `rle`

```
do.call(rbind, apply(input[-1], 1, function(x) {
       first_o_loc <- unname(which(x == 0)[1] + 1)
       first_o_name <- names(x)[first_o_loc-1]
       rl <- rle(x)
       rl1 <- within.list(rl,  {
             i1 <- cumsum(values == 0) == 1
             values <- values[i1]
             lengths <- lengths[i1]})
        streak_1 <- unname(rl1$lengths[2])
      data.frame(first_o_name, first_o_loc, streak_1)}))
#   first_o_name first_o_loc streak_1
#1            i9          10        5
#2            i4           5        4
#3            i6           7        8
#4            i8           9        4
#5            i9          10        5
#6          <NA>          NA       NA
#7            i1           2        5
#8            i3           4        8
#9            i2           3       NA
#10           i3           4        2
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, in row 4 of your output, `streak_1` should be `4`, not `NA`. The code is not handling the consecutive `0` values in this row correctly.

Comment: @DSH I was looking at the other answer and it was also NA.  Also, your last row seems to have some typo.  So, I was under the impression that there is some mixup

Comment: @DSH I updated the answer.  It was only a small fix as I had doubt earlier whether the consecutive 1s should be counted only after a single 0 or consecutive 0s